# SharePoint 2013 Custom Timer Job - Unable to schedule to execute every 3 hours

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, schedule

I have a timer job that needs to be executed every 3 hours. Unfortunately, SharePoint's scheduling classes do not facilitate this. How can I achieve this?

**Suggestion 1:**
Thought of running the timer job every hour and maintaining a counter value, hence when the counter reaches 3, I will execute my logic and then reset the counter back to 0. To follow this appraoch I can store the counter value in 2 ways (There maybe more):

1. Store in the web.config for retrieval and update (AppSettings)
2. Maintain a SharePoint list to manage the counter value

which way is better to maintain the counter? or is there an easier approach to executing every 3 hours?

Comment: Can you not set `SPMinuteSchedule` to run every 180 minutes?

Comment: Tried that and got the 'Message: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  Parameter name: value' error.

Comment: Could very well be an (undocumented) limit on 59 or something then

Comment: Yep. That's my guess as well. Unfortunately SPHourlySchedule does not have an Interval property.

Comment: Yep, this supports that: http://blogs.msdn.com/markarend/archive/2007/01/16/spschedule-fromstring-recurrencevalue-syntax-format-for-recurrence-value.aspx. You could possible store a value in the farm propertybag and do your logic on the count of three

Comment: Or store it in the timer jobs properties might work. Not sure if you are able to update thos properties from within the timer job though..

Comment: Or move the logic to a console app and schedule it every 3 hours through task scheduler.

Comment: This might be not the exact solution but this is what we did when we had a requirement for end users to configure when the job should run (which hour). We created a list item in a configuration list which could hold comma separated time values. The timer job was made to execute every fifteen minutes and read this list. If current time range was equal to or within the time specified in the list, the actual code logic would then be executed or else ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you care what hours it runs at as long as it is a 3 hour interval?

You could have your job scheduled to run every hour. When it runs, get the current hour and use a modulo operation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to see if it is a multiple of 3.

For e.g.

1 mod 3 = 1, don't run.

2 mod 3 = 2, don't run.

3 mod 3 = 0, run.

4 mod 3 = 1, don't run.

5 mod 3 = 2, don't run.

6 mod 3 = 0, run.

etc...

I believe this should work for both 12 and 24 hour clocks.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom list or file to LOG just one entry for your timerjob. schedule your timer job to run based on SPMinuteSchedule once in an hour. so basically it will run every hour but before you run actual task, LOG in your list or file that it is starting up for the 1st time. you can log date and time as well. next time when it will run, check the log entry if the last date time plus datediff is >=2 hour as compared to current time so then run the actual task and at end of actual task, update the list item entry to put new time in. this way atleast your actual task will be run every 2 hour but timer job will run every hour.

This is just a workaroud. This will cause load on server but no choice.